# (sml) I want to count the number of corresponding values in the list

Tags: sml

I would like to know the number of cases in which 1 dollar can be expressed in 1,5,10,20,50 cents.
For example, the  `count(100,[50,25])` is:
Because 50 * 1 + 25 * 2, `it = 3:int is printed.`
However, in my code, only the front part of the list is printed, so even if I `count (100,[50,25])`, `it = 2:int is printed.`
In other words, My code is not taking advantage of the whole list.
How do I solve this?

SML coin count function:

```
fun count(x,[]) = 0
| count (x,y::ys) =
let val cnt = 0
in if y*2 = x then cnt+2
else if y*4 = x then cnt + 4
else if y*10 = x then cnt + 10
else if y*10 = x then cnt + 10
else if y*20 = x then cnt + 20
else count(x-y,ys)
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens as you evaluate your test expression of `count (100, [50, 25])`.

`cnt` is `0`, `y` is `50`, and `ys` is `[25]`.

`y` times `2` *does* equal `100`, so it returns `cnt+2` which is `2`. Nothing further happens.

When it comes to recursion, remember than the parameter list to a function is your means of communication. It seems like `cnt` is something that should be passed as a parameter so you can update it between recursive calls.

With `count(x, []) = 0` you already have an exit point that will stop the recursion.

Edit: Based on comments, it looks like you're trying to figure out how many times each value in a list goes into a value `x`.

So the end result of your recursive function isn't a single integer. It's a list of integers. Or better yet, of tuples containing the value to look for, and the number of times it goes into `x`.

So if the list is empty, the result is obvious.

```
fun count(x, []) = []
```

It's an empty list. Otherwise, we need to append something onto a list.

```
fun count(x, []) = []
  | count(x, y::ys) = 
      (y, x div y) :: count(x, ys)
```

Of course, we also have functions like `map` that basically do this for us.

```
fun count(x, lst) = List.map (fn y => (y, x div y)) lst
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
I'm actually self-study in Standard ML.
So I don't think there's any place to get help, so I'd like to ask you one more time. Is that okay?

I understand that there are 50 in y and 25 in ys.
But since y is 50, cnt is increased by 1 and ys is 25, cnt is increased by 2,
When y+ys becomes x, you want to create a function that returns cnt.
But when I wrote x=y+ys, I got an error.

Is the approach to this list wrong? So how is it accessible?

Comment: Um, I'm sorry. I don't think I've explained it in detail.
The function I'm making is simply to find the number of cases.
For example, if the input value is count (100,[50,25]), then the input value can be 100 through 50 and 25.
There are three ways: 50, 50), (25, 25, 25), and 25.
So to write a function when y = 50, ys = 25
In the list, we are looking for a function that can compare the current element y and the next element ys. But since there's no data, it's impossible with sml. I'm suspicious. Can I get some help if you know any possible ways?